# Why need to specify the OS name when choosing to installing it later?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have just installed VMWare (for the fact that it's more performant that VirtualBox when it comes to hypervisors - type 1 # type 2).

I found something that did trigger me but I couldn't find any explanation for it.

When trying to create a new virtual machine on VMWare, I have chosen that I'll install my operating system later. However, the VMWare asks me later what OS is that so that I can move forward with configuring my virtual machine!

Does anyone of you have any idea why I'm asked to specify what OS I'll be installing even if I chose that I'll be installing it later?

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_newguest_setup_simple_steps.html

> The New Virtual Machine Wizard uses this information to
>
> - Select appropriate default values, such as the amount of memory needed
> - Name files associated with the virtual machine
> - Adjust settings for optimal performance
> - Work around special behaviors and bugs within an operating system